# Converting JSON to list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity (C#) project and trying to convert JSON data from an API to a list of dictionaries. I'm trying to use Unity's JSONSerialization, but I'm not sure what to do.

In the documentation, it says the following, and I was wondering if anyone could guide me to how I can convert the JSON? Sorry for the easy question as I'm new to C# and in the other languages I use like Javascript/Python, this is quite easily done.

> Passing other types directly to the API, for example primitive types
>   or arrays, is not currently supported. For now you will need to wrap
>   such types in a class or struct of some sort.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

The JSON returned is as follows and is a list of dictionaries, and each dictionary has two keys (_id and firstName).

```
[{"_id":"xxx", "firstName":"Brayann"}, {"_id":"yyy", "firstName":"Peter"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Create object in which you will `Deserialize` the json. Call `ToDictionary` after that.

Full example: [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rw2vdR)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"[{ ""_id"":""xxx"", ""firstName"":""Brayann""}, { ""_id"":""yyy"", ""firstName"":""Peter""}]";

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootListObject>>(json)
                             .ToDictionary(x=> x.id, y=> y.firstName);
}

public class RootListObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="_id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't deserialize as enumarable of dictionary but you can create a class for this purpose which is more reasonable:

```
public class SomeDataType
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize as `List<SomeDataType>`.

Even if you really require the dictionary you can add a `ToDictionary` method to your class.